# Does an Inflatable boat w a 4hp motor need a license in Ontario?

Tags: boats, canada, outboard-engine

I bought a 4-person inflatable boat (around $600). I would like to equip that with a 4HP 4-Stroke outboard motor. I'm not sure if I need a licence for that in Ontario, Canada. In addition, I believe this is more of a toy than a boat, so is this the same "Inflatable boat" that is addressed on some internet pages?

[image]

Comment: Which internet pages?

Comment: Not a real answer, but for 600$ I'd expect something more than a toy.

Comment: It's not much more than a toy, you'd have to be careful how powerful an engine you fitted, but it can be done using standard off the shelf fittings.

Comment: @WeatherVane Please post your comment if you want, I want to tag it as the answer!

Comment: I'd be careful about where you take it. Anything other than flatwater and you'll run into issues, motor or not. $600 is dirt cheap for a raft. It shouldn't be used on whitewater or in the ocean. It is definitely more of a toy than a boat. Have fun, but be smart and safe using appropriate gear for the task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [Government of Canada](https://tc.canada.ca/en/marine-transportation/marine-safety/licensing-pleasure-craft) website says:

> **Licensing a pleasure craft**
>
> A vessel used for pleasure, recreation, or daily living is a pleasure craft.
>
> **Determining whether a Pleasure Craft Licence is required**
>
> Every pleasure craft must have a Pleasure Craft Licence, with the following exceptions:
>
> - a pleasure craft using a motor with ***less than 10 horsepower*** (7.5 kW)
> - a pleasure craft that has a vessel registration
> - a pleasure craft that was purchased less than 90 days previously (this is a grace period, during which the new owner must carry documentation with their name and address and the purchase date)

So the answer looks like "No, you do not need a licence".

Comment: Note that while the boat does not need to be licensed, the operator does need a [Pleasure Craft Operator Card](https://www.boat-ed.com/canada/ontario/)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate answers to the question:

**1. Regarding licensing the boat:** No you do not need to license the boat as it less than 10hp (7.5kw)

**1. Regarding having a boating license to operate the boat:** Yes are required to have an [Ontario boating license](https://myboatcard.com/ontario-boating-license/) to operate the boat. You can get your boating license online. It takes around 4 hours, costs $40 and never expires.